# High load on a particular time

Tags: centos, sar

I am facing one odd problem in one of my remote servers (Centos 6). Its load became high by 09:30 AM and became normal by 09:40. See my SAR -q on 2 days.

```
09:00:01 PM         4       199      0.95      0.54      0.50
09:10:01 PM         2       201      0.43      0.68      0.61
09:20:01 PM         2       199      0.79      0.87      0.75
09:30:01 PM         5       209      2.47      1.50      0.97
09:40:02 PM        10       209      2.81      2.91      2.01
09:50:01 PM         2       202      0.98      3.60      3.43
10:00:01 PM         2       210      0.68      1.08      2.14



09:10:02 PM         2       207      0.51      0.50      0.57
09:20:01 PM         1       203      0.36      0.51      0.53
09:30:01 PM         2       213      3.43      2.04      1.10
09:40:01 PM         3       205      0.72      1.47      1.42
09:50:01 PM         1       203      0.22      0.57      0.98
10:00:01 PM         3       202      0.63      0.58      0.77
10:10:01 PM         2       203      0.47      0.46      0.62
```

This is happening daily. I could not find any cronjobs which executes at this time. Also, I cant access my server at that time. Is there any alternatives for SAR which shows the package/script which is responsible for the CPU Load?

Answer (score 2):

Process accounting should help track down which process is loading down the system.  In Centos the package name is psacct.

[Tecmint](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/) has an article on starting with process accounting.

Comment: This didnt helped me Rik. I have installed this on my server. But there is no command in process accounting to check which process consumed more CPU on a particular time.

Comment: "dump-acct  /var/account/pacct" will dump the raw data in a (semi) human readable format.  "man 5 acct" should help you figure out what the fields are.  Another possibility is to run top in batch mode with delay set to something on the order of 15-60 seconds and the output redirected to a file.